# IOS7: UITabBarController's "more" tab design is is disturbed

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

I'm using `UITabBarController` in `storyboard` in my project. The project is already coded with `iOS6` sdk. Now I'm working on its `iOS7` compatibility. I had customized the design of "`more`" tab's `tableview`  by providing my own `datasource` and it's working perfectly in `iOS6`. Strangely in `iOS7` the design is disturbed. Plz see following images for more elaboration.

**iOS6:**

[image: ios 6 screenshot]

**iOS7:**

[image: ios 7 screenshot]

Finally here is the code:-

```
-(void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tbController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController {

    UITabBarController *tabBarController = (UITabBarController *)self.window.rootViewController;

    UINavigationController *navCtr=(UINavigationController *)viewController;
    UITableView *moreTable = (UITableView *)tabBarController.moreNavigationController.topViewController.view;
    moreTable.dataSource = nil;
    if ([[navCtr.viewControllers lastObject] isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UIMoreListController")]){
        moreTableViewDataSource=[[MoreTableViewDataSource alloc] init];
        moreTable.dataSource = moreTableViewDataSource;
        [moreTable setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [moreTable setSeparatorStyle:UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone];
    }

}
```

**MoreTableViewDataSource.h**

```
@interface MoreTableViewDataSource : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{

}

@property  (strong, nonatomic) id<UITableViewDataSource> originalDataSource;

-(MoreTableViewDataSource *) initWithDataSource:(id<UITableViewDataSource>) dataSource;

@end
```

**MoreTableViewDataSource.m**

```
@implementation MoreTableViewDataSource

-(MoreTableViewDataSource *) initWithDataSource:(id<UITableViewDataSource>) dataSource
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        self.originalDataSource = dataSource;
    }

    return self;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    return 48.0;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)table numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return 5;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    MoreTabCell *cell = (MoreTabCell*)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"MoreTabCell"];
    if (cell==nil) {
        cell = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MoreTabCell" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            cell.titleLbl.text=NSLocalizedString(@"approach", nil);
            break;
        case 1:
            cell.titleLbl.text=NSLocalizedString(@"opening_time", nil);
            break;
        case 2:
            cell.titleLbl.text=NSLocalizedString(@"weather", nil);
            break;
        case 3:
            cell.titleLbl.text=NSLocalizedString(@"ticket", nil);
            break;
        case 4:
            cell.titleLbl.text=NSLocalizedString(@"contact", nil);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    cell.titleLbl.textColor=[UIColor lightBlueColor];
    [cell.titleLbl setFont:[UIFont setGothicFontBoldWithSize:14.0]];
    [cell.imgView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"moreIcon%d",indexPath.row+1]]];
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
    return cell;
}
@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying on my own, I've discovered that the trick is to set the delegate of the tableview to a custom one or `nil`. Since `UIMoreListController` fill out the title and other stuff in `tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Hope this will help.

Comment: you're right. Although by setting the delegate nil you lose the tabbarcontroller's auto selection, but a custom delegate will do. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making your own `titleLbl` instance in the cell, why not simply position and style the existing `titleLabel` the same way? I am not sure why it is happeneing because you haven't uploaded the code for `MoreTabCell`, but you can try setting the `titleLabel.text = nil;` if you don't want to stop using `titleLbl`.